# Ruby 1.9, Rails 3 and Unicode: code won't recognize Unicode characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to upgrade some tests as we move our app from Rails 2 on 1.8.7 to Rails 3 on Ruby 1.9.2.  The tests basically ensure that database objects can be named with unicode characters, to provide international support.

The tests basically look like this:

```
#encoding: utf-8
'ä' =~ /\S/ # this passes
'ä' =~ \/w/ # this fails, apparently passed on 1.8.7
model = Model.create!(:name => '§äè®') # this causes a "Name must include at least one letter or number" validation error, which means Ruby (or Rails) is seeing the name as being blank
```

This is all fundamentally basic and very simplified for the purposes of posting here, but these are what fail.  Is there anything else I need to be looking at here?  I know Ruby doesn't play well with Unicode, but this pretty much has to be left in.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is working as intended:

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3181

Changed to 'ä' =~ /\p{L}/ got it to work.